# Number Guesser: Loop Won't Loop Back

Tags: python, loops

The goal is to get the program to take turns asking player 1 and player 2 what they think their number is, and give a hint that its "too high" or "too low" if they get it incorrect. The program stops when one player guesses correctly. The problem is that for some reason it will not loop back to asking player 1 to guess after player 2 answers incorrectly. Anyone know how to fix?

```
import random
playerOneNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)
playerTwoNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)

print("\n")
print("Guess your numbers \n")
print("Player 1 go first")
guessOne = int(input())

while guessOne != playerOneNumber:
    print("Incorrect")
    if guessOne > playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too high \n")
    if guessOne < playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too low \n")
    print("Player two, try to guess your number.")
    guessTwo = int(input())
print("Correct that was the number \n")
print("Player One's number was: ")
print(playerOneNumber)
print("\n")
print("Player two's number was: ")
print(playerTwoNumber)

while guessTwo != playerTwoNumber:
    print("Incorrect \n")
    if guessTwo > playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too high")
    if guessTwo < playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too low")
    print("Player one, try to guess your number.")
    guessOne = int(input())
print("Correct that was the number \n")
print("Player One's number was: ")
print(playerOneNumber)
print("\n")
print("Player two's number was: ")
print(playerTwoNumber)
```

I tried combining them into one loop but that did not work out and just resulted in the same issue.

Program keeps consistently printing "Player 2, try to guess your number"

Comment: Instead of repeating code make a function. That function will do one thing that if you need to do more than once you can call as many times as you want. Anytime you repeat a line of code means that probably there's a better way of doing that. Use functions

Comment: I think you want to loop each round rather than repeatedly asking a given player for a number.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping around each player making guesses, I think you want to loop or repeat a round of each player making a guess. If during a round someone guesses correctly, you end the round/game by breaking out of the loop. Note I made the game's range 1-9 for testing

```py
import random
playerOneNumber = random.randrange(1, 10)
playerTwoNumber = random.randrange(1, 10)

print("=================")
print("Guess your numbers")
print("Player 1 go first")
print("=================")

while True:
    guess = int(input("Player One, Guess a number: "))
    if guess == playerTwoNumber:
        print("\tCorrect. You Win!")
        break
    if guess < playerTwoNumber:
        print("\tToo Low")
    else:
        print("\tToo High")

    guess = int(input("Player Two, Guess a number: "))
    if guess == playerOneNumber:
        print("\tCorrect. You Win!")
        break
    if guess < playerOneNumber:
        print("\tToo Low")
    else:
        print("\tToo High")

print()
print(f"Player One's number was: {playerOneNumber}")
print(f"Player Two's number was: {playerTwoNumber}")
```

Now, you might notice that the code for dealing with each player is essentially the same and that might lead us to create a method to handle each player. Perhaps something like:

```py
import random

def make_guess(name, opponent_number):
    guess = int(input(f"{name}, Guess a number: "))
    if guess == opponent_number:
        print("\tCorrect. You Win!")
        return True

    if guess < opponent_number:
        print("\tToo Low")
        return False

    print("\tToo High")
    return False


print("=================")
print("Guess your numbers")
print("Player 1 go first")
print("=================")

playerOneNumber = random.randrange(1, 10)
playerTwoNumber = random.randrange(1, 10)
while True:
    if make_guess("Player One", playerTwoNumber):
        break

    if make_guess("Player Two", playerOneNumber):
        break

print()
print(f"Player One's number was: {playerOneNumber}")
print(f"Player Two's number was: {playerTwoNumber}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that!
Use a While true loop, and some simple if

```
    import random
    
    playerOneNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)
    playerTwoNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)
    
    guessOne = None
    GuessTwo = None
    
    #This loop makes your code running until something stops it (in this case, until a player doesn't guess the number)
    while True:
        if guessOne != playerOneNumber:
            guessOne = int(input("Player2, type a number from 1 to 100: "))
            if guessOne == playerOneNumber:
                print("Correct, that was the number Player1!")
                #Exits from main loop
                break
            elif guessOne < playerOneNumber:
                print("Too low.")
            else:
                print("Too high.")
        
        if GuessTwo != playerTwoNumber:
            GuessTwo = int(input("Player2, type a number from 1 to 100: "))
            if GuessTwo == playerTwoNumber:
                print("Player 2 guessed correctly!")
                #Exits from main loop
                break
            elif GuessTwo < playerTwoNumber:
                print("Too low.")
            else:
                print("Too high.")
        
    print("Correct, that was the number\n")
    
    print("Player One's number was: ")
    print(playerOneNumber)
    print("\n")
    print("Player two's number was: ")
    print(playerTwoNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first while loop never ends if guessOne is wrong, hence, it repeats.

Try the below method

```
game = True
while game:
#player1 code here
if guess == answer:
  game = False 
if guess != answer:
  #player2 code here
   if p2guess == answer:
      game = False
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are making a loop for each player so your code will keep asking the player one for it's guess until he respond correctly.
2. to  make the program take turns you need to put both players within the loop and keep asking player one then player two until someone guess correctly you break out of the loop.
   so this is my version of code.
   give it a try and for any more info feel free to ask again.

```
import random
playerOneNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)
playerTwoNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)

print("\n")
print("Guess your numbers \n")
print("Player 1 go first")

while True:
    print("Player one, try to guess your number.")
    guessOne = int(input("player one guess: "))
    if guessOne > playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too high \n")
    if guessOne < playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too low \n")
    if guessOne == playerOneNumber: # if player one guess was correct
        winner = "one"   # we set winner to one 
        break   # and break the loop else we continue looping
    print("Player two, try to guess your number.")
    guessTwo = int(input("player two guess: "))
    if guessTwo > playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too high")
    if guessTwo < playerTwoNumber:
        print("Too low")
    if guessTwo == playerTwoNumber: # same here if plyer two guess was correct 
        break  # we break else we keep looping

if winner == "one": # we check who is the winner 
    print()
    print("winner is player one")
    print("Correct that was the number")
    print("Player One's number was: ")
    print(playerOneNumber)
    print()
else: # if the winner is not one for sure it's number two
    print()
    print("winner is player two")
    print("Correct that was the number \n")
    print("Player two's number was: ")
    print(playerTwoNumber)
    print("\n")
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop should be around both players guesses. To further simplify the code the guessing behavior can be put inside a function.

```py
import random

def check_guess(truth, player_name):
    guess = int(input(f"{player_name}, Guess a number: "))
    if guess == truth:
        print("\tCorrect. You Win!")
        return True
    if guess < truth:
        print("\tToo Low")
    else:
        print("\tToo High")
    return False

playerOneNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)
playerTwoNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)

print("=================")
print("Guess your numbers")
print("Player 1 go first")
print("=================")

while True:
    if check_guess(playerTwoNumber, 'Player One'):
        break
    if check_guess(playerOneNumber, 'Player Two'):
        break

print()
print(f"Player One's number was: {playerOneNumber}")
print(f"Player Two's number was: {playerTwoNumber}")
```